# Kubernetes ingress css and jv not found

Tags: html, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, metallb

I created a kubernetes cluster using `kubeadm`. Services are declared as `ClusterIP`. At the moment I'm trying to deploy my app as ingress of type `loadbalancer` with Metallb but I faced some problems. If I deploy my app as ingress some jv and css components are not found. There was no problem running the application as a service but the problem appeared while I used Ingress. It is an ASP.NET Core application

My Ingress source:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: taco-ingress
spec:
  rules:
   - host: tasty.taco.com
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /web1
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
             name: web1
             port:
               number: 80
       - path: /web2
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
             name: web2
             port:
               number: 80
```

My Deployment source:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web1
  labels:
    app: taco
    taco: web1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: taco
      task: web1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: taco
        task: web1
        version: v0.0.1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: taco
        image: yatesu0x00/webapplication1:ingress-v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web2
  labels:
    app: taco
    taco: web2
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: taco
      task: web2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: taco
        task: web2
        version: v0.0.1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: taco
        image: yatesu0x00/webapplication2:ingress-v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

My Service source:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web1
spec:
  ports:
  - targetPort: 80
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: taco
    task: web1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web2
spec:
  ports:
  - targetPort: 80
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: taco
    task: web2
```

The html file of the app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Epic Website - (⌐■_■)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>     
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home2">Home2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home/ItWorks">Click me!</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                <h2>Want this taco?</h2>
    <pre>
    {\__/}
    ( ●.●)
    ( >
    </pre>
     
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - <a href="/Home/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>   
    </footer>
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/darkmode-js@1.5.7/lib/darkmode-js.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/site.js?v=8ZRc1sGeVrPBx4lD717BgRaQekyh78QKV9SKsdt638U"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

If I open up the console in browser I can see that there is `404 not found` on all elements of type `<script>`.

Comment: Could you please make [your issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by editing and adding following information to your question: `yaml` definition files of your services and deployments, information about how did you setup your Kubernetes cluster - `kubeadm`,`minikube` or other solution?

Comment: Hello Mikolaj I edited my post and added the missing informations

Answer (score 2):

If you look closer in the logs, you can find that the cause of your problem is that your app is requesting static content (example for `css/site.css` file)  in the path `tasty.taco.com/css/site.css` and as Ingress Controller doesn't have definition for prefix `/css` in it's definition it is returning 404 error code.

The static content is available in the following path `tasty.taco.com/web1/css/site.css` - look that I used `web1` prefix so Ingress knows to which service re-direct this request.

Generally, using annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` in the apps that are requesting static content often causes issues like this.

Fix for this is **not** to use this annotation and add to your app possibility to setup base URL, in your example by using  [`UsePathBaseMiddleware` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.extensions.usepathbasemiddleware?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

> Represents a middleware that extracts the specified path base from request path and postpend it to the request path base.

For detailed steps, I'd recommend following steps presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625822/asp-net-core-2-2-kubernetes-ingress-not-found-static-content-for-custom-path/57212033#57212033).